# Can call API with any JWT token

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

I am writing an app where front end users will make calls to the back end through an API. I have implemented JWT where users can register and when they try to login they will get a JWT in response and I can make other calls then to the API with the JWT in the header. If the JWT is left out of the header, the call will be failed. The basics work as expected.
The issue I face tho is that I can generate my own custom JWT, assign it to a header and be able to successfully call the back end.
I have followed numerous tutorials online and finding this topic pretty confusing and very complex to fully grasp. I have no doubt it is something simple I am missing from my code but I can't see what.

Here is what I have done so far;

**AuthenticationFilter**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User credentials = new     ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            credentials.getUsername(),
                            credentials.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>()
                    )
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)     authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() +     EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();
        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);

    }
}
```

**AuthorizationFilter**

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter     {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if(StringUtils.isBlank(header) || ! StringUtils.startsWith(header, TOKEN_PREFIX)){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthentication(request);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(token)){
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(user)){
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**WebSecurity**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))                    
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

As I said I am finding this topic fairly hard, so I'm sure there could be simple errors within my code. If you can help or shed light on my problem in any way, it'd be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the critical code from your servlet filter which checks the JWT:

```
String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(token)){
    String user = Jwts.parser()
        .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes())
        .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
        .getBody()
        .getSubject();

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(user)){
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
    }
```

If you look closely at what you are doing, you will see that your logic is to extract the subject from the JWT.  This much is correct.  But you then authorize that user so long as the subject is not blank.  In other words, *any* user will be authorized by your current logic.  Instead, you would typically do something like this:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(user)){
    // check that user against a database/cache
    // if the account is active etc. THEN authorize the user
}
```

Typically, after extracting the subject/username from the JWT, you would hit the database/cache to check if that user's account is still active.  If not, then you would return 401 to the calling app.  A JWT by itself does not mean the user is authorized, because at some point you may revoke that user's token, the token could expire, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, it makes more sense now. I think I am getting it more n more now. So in the AuthenticationFilter class I set the user as the subject and in the if block you have in your answer, I have to check that the user from the token is in the db, if thats true, then return ok. Would I be right in that?

Comment: @Dan No, you don't set the user.  But the rest you said makes sense.  You need to _extract_ information from the JWT, such as usernamd and expiry.  If you don'f know this user or the JWT is expired, then you would not authenticate.